# Find orders placed on last day of any month using sargable query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote this query to find orders placed on last day of any month.

I know this approach is not recommended if orderdate is indexed. What approach should i use to make it sargable?

```
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.custid, o.empid
from  sales.Orders o
where day(o.orderdate) in (30, 31) 
         or (month(o.orderdate) = 02 and day(o.orderdate)= 28) 
         or (month(o.orderdate) = 02 and day(o.orderdate)= 29);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with computed columns:

```
alter table Orders add column nextdayofmonth as day(dateadd(day, 1, orderdate));

create index orders_nextdayofmonth on orders(orders_nextdayofmonth);
```

The nextdayofmonth is for the *next* day, so leap years can easily be handled.  After all, the day after the "last day" is the "first day" of the next month.

Then phrase your query as:

```
where next_dayofmonth = 1
```

This expression is sargable.

Answer (score 1):

`DATEADD` is sargable:

```
WHERE DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, o.orderdate), 0) = 
      DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, o.orderdate) + 1, 0))
```

The first is just the old way to truncate the time from a `datetime`. The second adds one month, "truncates" the month and subtracts a day.

[Here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14569/0) a fiddle that returns the last day of the current month with the same "trick".

Comment: Can you explain this part `DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, o.orderdate) + 1, 0)) ` I'm not getting how +1 works here.

Answer (score 0):

This query would fail for leap years as it would give you 2 dates as the last day of the month in February.  To make it SARGable, you would need to take out the functions on the date column.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.custid, o.empid
from  sales.Orders o
where
day(o.orderdate)=day(DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0,o.orderdate) + 1, 0)))
```

The below query gives the last day of current month, replace getdate() with the date variable as shown above:

```
SELECT day(DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)))
```

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Is "=" not SARGable?

Comment: @Punter015 Putting columns in functions within your `WHERE` clause is not SARGable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do is:

```
select TOP 1 orderid, orderdate, custid, empid
from  sales.Orders 
ORDER BY orderdate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all dates that DAY part of its tomorrow is 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales.Orders
WHERE DAY(DATEADD(dd, 1, orderdate)) = 1
```